# SQL Server 2012 Management Tools - Basic not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-express

I made a fresh install of SQL Server 2012 Express and Management Tools - Basic onto a new computer and none of the tools in the Integration Services folder will run. It gives the following message:

> ERROR: The Execute Package Utility requires Management Tools - Basic or Business Intelligence Studio to be installed by the SQL Server 2012 Standard, Enterprise, Business Intelligence, or Evaluation Edition.

Its the Execute Package Utility that I'm after, but the Deployment Wizard and Project Conversion Wizard also give the error.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling but that doesn't seem to make a difference. This is on Windows 7 Pro 64 bit computer.

[image: Tools install succeeded notice]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems obvious now, but the problem was that I was installing a SQL Server Express version. Even though it installed the needed components it would not run them. I downloaded the Eval version and it worked.

In my defense, the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 site does list SSDT as included with Express with Advanced Services:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=SQL.110).aspx

Comment: Just a comment for anyone else really - if you get any issue with an older version of SSMS you can now download the latest bits for free without the full sql install. It is now at version 17 and changes are happening pretty quickly. The current download page is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms "Download SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)". The latest bits are backwards compatible so always get the latest (unless your using query analyzer and sql 7!) :)

Comment: Do the individual bits include the Integration Services and SSDT? I need to build and run 2012 SSIS packages.